# Jquery - Change Button Function

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery and I'm trying to write code that changes a clicked button both in text and function. Here is the code:

```
$('.button1').click(
    function() {
        $(this).val('Button2');
        $(this).removeClass('button1').addClass('button2');
    }
);

$('.button2').click(
    function() {
        alert('Button 2 Clicked');
    }
);
```

The problem is, the second event does not fire and call the alert.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to use .on();

Comment: The duplicate I posted isn't an exact duplicate, but the solution is the same. Event handlers are bound to _elements_, and changing the class of an element doesn't change the binding. In your case, you need to use event delegation. See the link.

Comment: If you just want to click the 2nd button, you can add this line to the first function: `$('.button2').click();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers are bound to elements, and changing the class of an element doesn't change the binding. In your case, you need to use event delegation.

From jQuery 1.7 onward, use [**`.on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for that:

```
$(document).on('click', '.button1', 
    function() {
        $(this).val('Button2');
        $(this).removeClass('button1').addClass('button2');
    }
);

$(document).on('click', '.button2', 
    function() {
        alert('Button 2 Clicked');
    }
);
```

If those have a common ancestor, (say a `<div id="container">`) it could be used instead of `document`: `$('#container').on('click', '.button2', ...`. It will work as long as every `.button1` and `.button2` you want the click event are under that `div`.

Comment: That goes without saying, but, anyone wishing to edit the wiki answer, feel free to do it.